# Jquery append() refreshes page

Tags: jquery

I have a simple task of appending a row to a table, but for some reason after the append command is executed, the whole page gets refreshed. I tried to recreate it on fiddle, but in there I get a 404 error.

https://jsfiddle.net/9fp8scoj/3/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script >
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#add").click(function(){

                $("table tbody").append('<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Table</h3>
        </div>
        <form id="inputForm" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="first" placeholder="First name"/>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="last" placeholder="Last name"/>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="place" placeholder="Place"/>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" class="add-row" id="add">Add person</button>
        </form>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table id="people" class="table" style="width:100%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Firstname</th>
                        <th>Lastname</th>
                        <th>Place</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jon</td>
                        <td>Snow</td>
                        <td>Great Wall</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Arya</td>
                        <td>Stark</td>
                        <td>Winterfell</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: not sure how that jquery function even fires- there is no element with id `row` in your post

Comment: @GregH sorry, that's my bad. Fixed

Comment: Can you try putting `type="button"` on your input button with id `add`? `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" class="add-row" id="add">Add person</button>`

Comment: @GregH wow, that fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: button is  submit button, it submits the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button will default to a type of submit on most browsers (see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)) which will submit the form that it is wrapped in and trigger a page refresh as you're seeing. you need to add `type="button"` to the button that has id `add`

Answer (score 0):

You missed few things here. First of all you need to mention button type like `type="button"` button otherwise it treating as a submit button that's why it is refreshing the page due to form submit. Then correct your click selector. Also your button has 2 class `attribute` like `<button class="btn btn-primary" class="add-row"` it should `<button class="btn btn-primary add-row"`. See snippet I added below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <head>
        <title>TIN cw4 C</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script >
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#add").click(function(){
                    $("table tbody").append('<tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr>');
                });
            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title text-center">Table</h3>
            </div>
            <form id="inputForm" class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="first" placeholder="First name"/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="last" placeholder="Last name"/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="place" placeholder="Place"/>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary add-row" type="button" id="add">Add person</button>
            </form>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="people" class="table" style="width:100%;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Firstname</th>
                            <th>Lastname</th>
                            <th>Place</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jon</td>
                            <td>Snow</td>
                            <td>Great Wall</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Arya</td>
                            <td>Stark</td>
                            <td>Winterfell</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```